# Склоняется ли фамилия Котелевец?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилия Котелевец?

Comment: А как насчет того, что, когда о чем-то просите, надо говорить "пожалуйста"? А еще в школе Вам не объясняли, что в конце вопросительных предложений ставится вопросительный знак? А что предложения начинаются с большой буквы?

Comment: Большая буква - это хорошо. Но вот насчет "пожалуйста" можно поспорить. Ведь сайт специально предназначен для вопросов, и кто хочет - отвечает. Что-то я не видела "пожалуйста" в других вопросах.

Comment: Сначала меня это неприятно удивило: ни  здравствуйте, ни пожалуйста. Потом привыкла к особенностям этого форума.

Comment: На самом деле, это не особенности форума, это недостаток воспитания. Просто, сил не хватает воспитывать всех))))

Comment: Может, просто в интернете складывается своя этика? Более деловая, жесткая, без сантименов. Мне, кстати, она больше нравится: всякие там лишние раскланивания часто раздражают. Но это личная особенность. Может, потому, что я - математик.   
Я прихожу на форум почитать вопросы и, если могу, ответить. Так зачем же меня еще об этом просить? Логически это излишне.

Comment: В Интернете часто дейтвительно принято переходить сразу к сути. "Здравствуйте" в принципе не обязательно. А вот "спасибо" не помешает для подобных вопросов, имеющих актуальность только для автора. Разумеется, это не рекомнедация для всех и каждого, на каждом ресурсе эти вещи в принципе решпются по-своему. Как и с пресловутым ты/вы/Вы.

Comment: Кстати, я заметила, что на "соседнем" форуме ХэшКод многие обращаются к собеседнику на ты. Наверное, считается, что программирование - дело молодых )))

Comment: Нет, это давнишняя практика. Типа братства. Когда-то мы, конечно, были молодыми... Но главное, что сам факт приобщения к компьютеру (тогда еще говорили ЭВМ) делал причастного членом избранного - а значит и очень узкого - кружка. Типа братства. Как-то так.
Но надо сказать, что сейчас это далеко не везде.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о мужчине, то склоняется по падежам, как обычное слово, а если это женщина, то не склоняется вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема не со склонением (мужская склоняется, женская - нет), а с выбором формы.

Котелевец, Котелев(е)ца, Котелев(е)цу и т.д. Вот это надо уточнять у носителя. Если нет возможности, то наверное все-таки с беглой гласной: Котелевец, Котелевца, Котелевцу...

Comment: Автор спрашивает, "склоняется ли", а не "как склоняется". Думаю, что Fuchoin Kazuki точнее ответил на вопрос.